# WPF Usercontrol using staticresources with Meta.Vlc

Tags: wpf, vlc

I can set vlc options in an app by adding the following to the application.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="Application"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ADSNet35"
    StartupUri="Start.xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <Application.Resources>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:String}" x:Key="VlcOptions">
            <sys:String>-I</sys:String>
            <sys:String>--dummy-quiet</sys:String>
            <sys:String>--ignore-config</sys:String>
            <sys:String>--no-video-title</sys:String>
            <sys:String>--no-sub-autodetect-file</sys:String>
        </x:Array>  
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

and in the xaml

```
<wpf:VlcPlayer xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:Meta.Vlc.Wpf;assembly=Meta.Vlc.Wpf" x:Name="VlcPlayer1" VlcOption="{StaticResource VlcOptions}" />
```

and everything works great.

I have created a class library usercontrol and have used the following

```
UserControl x:Class="ucContainer"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <x:Array x:Key="VlcOptions" Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
            <sys:String>-I</sys:String>
            <sys:String>--dummy-quiet</sys:String>
            <sys:String>--ignore-config</sys:String>
            <sys:String>--no-video-title</sys:String>
            <sys:String>--no-sub-autodetect-file</sys:String>
        </x:Array>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources> 
<Grid>
        <wpf:VlcPlayer xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:Meta.Vlc.Wpf;assembly=Meta.Vlc.Wpf" x:Name="VlcPlayer1" VlcOption="{StaticResource VlcOptions}" />
</Grid>
```

When the usercontrol is created I get the following error:

System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Cannot convert the value in attribute 'VlcOption' to object of type 'System.String[]'. 'System.Windows.Markup.ArrayExtension' is not a valid value for property 'VlcOption'.

This is my first class library / usercontrol and hope someone can explain what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You can't declare the wpf namespace after the VlcPlayer element. Move xmlns:wpf to the <UserControl> root element to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I took out the `<ResourceDictionary>` tag and it worked fine.